ASP.NET Core 8 Web API: cannot register scoped service from singleton
In my API I register some services with AddHostedService that need some interfaces to be injected on them, for example:
Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHypervisorRepository, HypervisorRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloudStackDbUnitOfWork, CloudStackDbUnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory, MySqlCloudStackCoreConnectionFactory>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobUtility, JobUtility>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVdcUnitOfWork, VdcUnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService>();

CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService.cs:
public sealed class CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService : BackgroundService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    private readonly IJobUtility _jobUtility;
    private readonly IVdcUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory _connFactory;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly ILogger<CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService> _logger;
    
    public CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService(
        IServiceProvider provider,
        IJobUtility jobUtility,
        IVdcUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory connFactory,
        IMemoryCache cache,
        ILogger<CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _jobUtility = jobUtility;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _connFactory = connFactory;
        _cache = cache;
        _logger = logger;
    }

but after I launch the API the following Exception is thrown:

System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: CloudStackData.WebAPI.RefreshDiskTypeBackgroundService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Vdc.Libs.Data.IVdcUnitOfWork' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Vdc.Libs.Data.IVdcUnitOfWork' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'

After reading about this error I concluded I should add the CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService required services as singleton, not scoped, and so I tried:
Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHypervisorRepository, HypervisorRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloudStackDbUnitOfWork, CloudStackDbUnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory, MySqlCloudStackCoreConnectionFactory>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJobUtility, JobUtility>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IVdcUnitOfWork, VdcUnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService>();

And now the Exception thrown is:

System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: CloudStackData.WebAPI.RefreshDiskTypeBackgroundService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Vdc.Libs.Data.DbContextWrite' from singleton 'Vdc.Libs.Data.IVdcUnitOfWork'.

And here I started to be stuck.
VdcUnitOfWork is a custom class we created:
public sealed class VdcUnitOfWork : EFDbUnitOfWork<DbContextWrite>, IVdcUnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork, IDisposable, IDbContextWrapper
{
    public VdcUnitOfWork(DbContextWrite dbContext)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
}

And DbContextWrite is another custom class:
public abstract class DbContextWrite : DbContext
{
    protected DbContextWrite([NotNull] DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

The fact is after adding the hosted service with AddHostedService I cannot run the API anymore (I have four hosted services, but just put one for the sake of simplification).

For using scoped-Services in a HostedService, which is a singleton, you need to inject the IServiceScopeFactory (using primary constructors from .NET 8.0):
public sealed class CheckDatabaseHealthBackgroundService
      (IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
         // get scoped services:
         using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
         var jobUtility = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IJobUtility>();
         var unitOfWork = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IVdcUnitOfWork>();
         var memoryCache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();

         // Use services here
    }
}


You have to understand that singleton is longer lived, so to get the required services you have to control the scope, that means that at the point in time that you need them create a scope, or your unit of work might create it's own specific scope depending on your implementation. This issue comes up a lot when you mix background workers with your API or WFE logic. An alternative is to change the other services to singletons as well, but that is not usually a good idea

@ChrisSchaller Thx for elaborating more. Especially when using EF-Core DbContext and/or UnitOfWork Repos the Singleton is not an option and we would need the scoped context anyways.

Thanks both, @decius and ChrisSchaller, it is now indeed working, and we all learn (or refresh) something new everyday here with your mates developers.
